Quillen bundles and 2D CFTs
Roughly speaking, a (mathematical) genus-$0$ conformal field theory (CFT) is a projective symmetric
monoidal functor $Z$ from $C$ to $GrVec$ [1], where $GrVec$ is the category of graded complex vector spaces, and $C$ is roughly a category with a typical object being parametrized closed $1$-manifold, and morphisms being bordisms with complex structures (up to biholomorphisms). Hence, morphism space in $C$ is
naturally identified as the moduli space of complex structures of genus-$0$
Riemann surfaces with suitable amount of punctures. The term "projective" here
means that the image of each morphism is a linear operator modulo a non-zero
scalar. In particular, this gives a graded vector space $V = Z(S^{1})$ and a vertex
operator algebra structure on $V$ [1][2].
To remove the term "projective" in the definition of $Z$, we can redefine the
domain category: Instead of having the morphism spaces identified as the
moduli spaces, have each of them identified as a certain holomorphic line
bundle (with the zero section removed) over each of them. Indeed, to each
fixed Riemann surface, we only need to specify a non-zero scalar, the space
must be a (holomorphic) crossed product of the moduli space itself and
$\mathbb{C}^{\star}$.
Question Why must these holomorphic line bundles be the Quillen bundles
(which are abstractly defined as the determinant line bundle of some Fredholm
operators)?
Reference

[1] L. Kong, Conformal field theory and a new geometry
[2] Y. Huang, Two-dimensional conformal geometry and vertex operator algebras

